# How do you call for cats by breed in The Cat API?

Tags: python

I am using Python3 to call [The Cat API](https://docs.thecatapi.com/).

```
def get_cat_by_breed(breed_name):
    from requests import get
    from json import loads
    url = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search"
    breeds = [{"name": breed_name}]
    params = {"breeds": breeds,
              "api_key": api_key,
              "limit": 100,
              "page": 1}
    response = get(
        url=url,
        params=params)
    return loads(response.content)
```

This successfully gets a cat, but not of the specified `breed_name`. What am I doing wrong?

Also, how do you search for images of >=x pixels and >= y pixels?

Comment: https://docs.thecatapi.com/example-by-breed

Comment: @matt I had seen that but it a) does not give a Python example and b) does not show searching by breed name.

Comment: As the docs show, `breed_ids` or `breed_id` is a query parameter. Where in your code are you attempting to provide that?

Comment: @OneCricketeer As I mentioned, I would like to search by `breed_name`.

Comment: You can't, based on those docs. Each name is mapped to an ID. You need to use the ID

Comment: OK thanks. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: How do you search for images of >=x pixels?

Comment: Doubt that you can do that either. You'd have to download any image before you would be able to find its dimensions

Comment: OK thanks. I'll submit a ticket with them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well, but the breed name is not indicated for alle images. As you can see below, when I tried your code for "abys"

```py
[{'breeds': [], 'categories': [{'id': 5, 'name': 'boxes'}], 'id': 'hn', 'url': 'https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/hn.jpg', 'width': 1200, 'height': 1600}, {'breeds': [], 'id': '182', 'url': 'https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/182.jpg', 'width': 448, 'height': 336}]
```

The first result didn't had a breed name or ID... so I guess there is a mistake in the API response.
they do, however, have a height and width so it should be possible to request a specific size, IF the endpoint for this query exists. Else you could sort them yourself after you get the image